# Can i put my PO Box Address in Street Address field in google adsense?

Tags: google, google-adsense

Can i put my PO Box Address in Street Address field in google adsense ?

I mean here :
https://www.google.com/adsense/g-app-single-1?hl=en

can you give me examples.

Comment: Why not ask Google? Or just try it? And what kind of examples do you need? This looks like a yes or no question.

Answer (score 1):

yes, but with steps:

http://www.ehow.com/how_6811011_use-p_o_-box-google-adsense.html

Comment: I mean here : https://www.google.com/adsense/g-app-single-1?hl=en